# Align words starting on next line with first line's first character

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to neatly text-align the sentence with all words starting line 2 come under E (Enter) ?

```css
.question-arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  color: #b4c1c8;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #eceff1;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 22px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;width:300px">
  <div>
    <div class="question-arrow">&gt;</div>
    <label>Enter the number of customers who might be interested in purchasing your products and/or services each year?</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/anjanesh/rafop92e/

Comment: Give then label a padding left

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might float the arrow and reset [BFC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)*(block formatting context)* on label:

```css
.question-arrow
{
    float:left;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    color:#b4c1c8;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#eceff1;
    border-radius:25px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:22px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
label {
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div style="font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;width:300px">
    <div>
        <div class="question-arrow">&gt;</div>
        <label>Enter the number of customers who might be interested in purchasing your products and/or services each year?</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

or use flex:

```css
.question-arrow
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    color:#b4c1c8;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#eceff1;
    border-radius:25px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:22px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;width:300px">
    <div style="display:flex;">
        <div class="question-arrow">&gt;</div>
        <label>Enter the number of customers who might be interested in purchasing your products and/or services each year?</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I went with the `float:left;` solution as `display:flex;` seems to alter the size of the arrow. ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your container div like this:

```
<div style="font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;width:300px">
    <div class="same_heights">
        <div class="question-arrow">&gt;</div>
        <label>Enter the number of customers who might be interested in purchasing your products and/or services each year?</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And add this to your css:

```
.same_heights{
    display:flex;
}
```

What this does is tell your container div to make all its children the same height. This worked when I edited your fiddle.

Comment: it is indeed better to use class than inline style ;)